# Options to move C++ TCP server application to web

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, webassembly, emscripten

I have a C++ GDB Server application that runs on host and is currently integrated with Eclipse CDT to provide debugging support on different hardware platforms. Below is overall structure of it:

```
Eclipse CDT <-----> GDB <-------> MYGDBServerApp <------> Hardware Platform
```

This app listens on a port for communication with GDB. This works perfectly fine in desktop environment.

I am now evaluating options to move whole solution to web. For this, I need to move this native C++ GDB server application to web as well. For Cloud based IDE, I am using Eclipse Theia project and have developed an extension for it. Now, I am looking for options to somehow use this C++ application from browser as well.

I have tried to compile this app to WASM using emscripten but I ran into different problems. One problem is socket communication. As WASM script will be running in browser, it cannot open TCP sockets for communication. It can only use websockets and Emscripten documentation suggests to use some proxy server (websockify) to translates WebSockets traffic to normal TCP socket traffic.
I have following questions:

1. What are recommended options to use such application from browser?
2. Has someone tried this proxy-server approach in similar scenario. As per Emscripten [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/networking.html#emulated-posix-tcp-sockets-over-websockets), *This emulation is not very complete at the moment, it is likely that you will run into problems out of the box*
3. Is there any other better approach to reuse/port this application to web?

Comment: Is `MYGDBServerApp` running on the hardware platform? If yes, why do you need to write your own gdb server?

Comment: Websockets and TCP Sockets are not related. You cannot run an application in the browser via any language that depends on sockets. You will need an external server to handle those features.

Comment: @LouisGo No, MYGDBServerApp runs on host